# How to get comments posted by a specific account (channel) through YouTube Data API?

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm looking for the way to get comments posted by a specific account through YouTube Data API and make a list of them.

I know the way to get comments on a specific video by using ["CommentThreads"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads) resource, however my aim here is to specify the user (maybe by channelId or user name) and to fetch recent comments he or she posted on some YouTube videos.

If it is possible, I guess the resource I need to achieve this would be ["Activities"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities) because it seems to have a property named "comment". But I don't get how to do it. Is it possible? Or is it right to use YouTube Data API?

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, the YouTube Data API does not provide the info you need.

Comment: The [`Activities.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) API endpoint is used for completely different things. Moreover, this endpoint does not return [activity items](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#resource) that have [`type`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#snippet.type) be `comment`.